# Discerning class parameters in documentation/class reference

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, gtk3

Having some trouble reading the documentation for GTK+ 3. I've looked up and down for multiple class references that might clue me in. The one reference that I found that explicitly states the parameters passed when instantiating a class is outdated and missing several classes. The other 3 or 4 are laid out in a way that does not seem to explicitly state which parameters I need to pass.

The most complete class reference I've found is [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/index.html). Using "Button" as an example, it gives a list of properties, including label, relief, xalign, yalign, etc. Yet, it does not identify which I need to pass when instantiating.

This isn't specific to this documentation library, but it's the one causing me grief right now. Where do I need to look to find this information?

Edit: More specifically, I'm looking for the kwargs, as well as how the control class processes them. In the button example, inputting a string as an argument sets the label. However, I cannot find why this is the case in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GObject-based libraries from Python, you can rely on the following two rules of thumb for constructor arguments:

1. Using positional arguments in constructors is deprecated.
2. Keyword args correspond to writable properties.

So, for example for `Gtk.Button`, [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#properties) is where you'd find the allowed kwargs. Any property that has "w" (for "writable") listed under "Flags" can be set as a keyword arg when constructing the object.

As for your question about where to find info about the positional args: they're deprecated, and so not present in the modern API documentation. You can go back to the old [PyGTK API reference](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkbutton.html#constructor-gtkbutton) to see what's being emulated for compatibility, but I don't recommend writing any new code with positional constructor arguments.

Just use

```
button = Gtk.Button(label='Some text')
```

Comment: Very concise and informative explanation. Thank you very much!